# For loop, is it faster to check the size of a vector outside the loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, compiler-optimization, loop-invariant

My question is regarding time optimisation.
Is the for loop faster by doing:

```
std::vector<int> myVec = {0,1,2,3};
for(int i = 0; i < myVec.size(); i++){}
```

Or is it best practice to compute the size beforehand?

```
std::vector<int> myVec = {0,1,2,3};
int myVecSize = myVec.size();
for(int i = 0; i < myVecSize ; i++){}
```

I'm wondering here not only about pure time execution, but also if it could lead to some problems to do in a way or another

Comment: `std::vec` is meaningless.   If you mean `std::vector<int>` or something, say that.   The difference in typing is minimal, and there is no virtue in brevity that makes your question meaningless.

Comment: What is the type `std::vec`?

Comment: Most all compilers these days will optimize all this out for you in the *release build*, so it won't matter for your customers. But as developers, we often work exclusively with non-optimized *debug builds*, so the latter form might be faster in the local debug build... but if that code path doesn't get executed that often while running your program, it might not matter at all.

Comment: `for (auto i: myVec) {}` is the preferred way to iterate over a vector in most cases.

Comment: `for (auto& i : myVec)` if you're iterating over a collection of objects and you want to avoid the overhead of a copy.

Comment: Also important: [try and see](https://godbolt.org/g/6rj4Kn)

Comment: Not only is the compiler going to do the best job of that regardless of how you code it, it doesn't matter anyway. Fetching the vector from main memory into cache will account for virtually all the time - fraction of a microsecond. Just learn to program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not important at all. Optimizing compiler will remove those two or three lines, they do nothing.

Seriously. If compiler could deduce if a container is not changed in a loop, it would do optimization that you did manually. To help compiler to apply optimization you can even declare a container be constant (example for vector):

```
const std::vector<int> myVec = {0,1,2,3};
```

Comment: But how does one know what the compiler will optimise what should be manually optimised? Can you explain why the compiler can do this?

Comment: @WillVousden Read *doron* answer.

Comment: It is poor advice to rely on the optimiser to fix intrinsically inefficient code. Loop invariant expressions should be avoided as a matter of good practice.  Optimised code is generally hard to follow in a source-level debugger, so it is still advisable to write intrinsically efficient code.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, the compiler needs to call the `size` function every iteration of the loop. C++ does not have the concept of function purity and unless the compiler has visibility of the function definition, it cannot assume that the function has no side effects (like a logging statement).

Now an stl vector is defined in a header file, so the compiler does have visibility. Now given `size`'s simplicity, it will may well be inlined and optimized away.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the answer depends on your opinion.   But, assuming you're looping over elements of a standard container (like `std::vector<int>`), then it also depends on what the loop does.

If the loop does anything that resizes the vector, then it is NECESSARY to compare the index against the size on every iteration, since resizing a vector invalidates all iterators and can result in an index being used when it is no longer valid (resulting in undefined behaviour).

As a rough rule, if you're not resizing the vector in the loop body, it is often better to use iterators than indices.   Use of indices requires the vector's `operator[]()` function to find the element of interest on every call, whereas iterators provide more direct access to the particular element

```
  // case where vector is not resized

 for (std::vector<int>::iterator i = myVec.begin(), end = myVec.end();  i != end; ++i)
 {
      //    do something with the iterator i
 }
```

In C++11 and later, if the loop body does not resize the container, simply used a range-based for loop that works on every element

```
for (auto &element : myVec)
{
     // do something with element
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I would use the first option without the myVecSize variable, since it is redundant and makes the code less readable and unnecessary longer. Also I think these reasons mentioned above are more important in coding than a execution time difference u probably won't even ever notice.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, it depends :-)

If the vector is a local variable then a smart enough compiler should be able to infer that the size cannot change during the body of the loop, even if functions with an hidden implementation are called.

If the vector has not been locally created (e.g. it has been passed to the function with a reference - irrelevant if a `const` reference or not) then the compiler must be paranoid and anything that cannot be fully understood in the body of the loop (i.e. anything that cannot possibly be inlined down to elementary operations) may in theory change the size of the vector so the generated code will have to check for a possibly changed size and relocation at each iteration.

Note that even in cases the vector has been locally created the compiler must assume that any external function that is informed about the address of the vector object may immediately or even in future mutate the object... for example in:

```
void foo() {
    std::vector<int> myvec{1,2,3,4};
    printf("%p\n", (void *)&myvec); // Address of the vector object
    for (int i=0; i<int(myvec.size()); i++) {
        printf("Hello, world (%i)\n", int(myvec.size()));
        printf("Hello again (%i)\n", int(myvec.size()));
    }
}
```

the compiler cannot assume that the loop will be executed 4 times and it cannot even assume that between the first and second call to the `printf` function the size didn't change.
The reason is that the address of the object has been passed to a global external function in the call outside the loop, and this function could have changed the object and even could store away that address to mutate it on later calls.

In the above case may be a compiler could special-flag `printf` to know that is a "well behaving" function that is not going to do things like that... but if instead of `printf` this was a generic user defined `C++` function with a body that is not known at compile time then the "paranoid mode" will have to be used.

There is unfortunately no portable C++ way to declare a function to be side-effect free and to reassure a compiler that this kind of bad stuff is not going to happen.